# How to use Emacs Application Framework as Default PDF viewer?

Tags: pdf

I recently discovered the Emacs Application Framework, which works quite nice for me. The only thing that's bothering me is, that I need to explicitly call `eaf-open` on a file, to open it with the framework.
I tried to associate eaf with the file extension via `(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.[pP][dD][fF]\\'" . eaf-mode))` but to no avail.

How can I tell Emacs that it should open PDF files with eaf?

Comment: I haven't tested this, but you could create a function that takes the name of the current file and call eaf-open with it. Then add this function in the hook of doc-view-mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the Emacs file association way by the following code.

```lisp
(defun adviser-find-file (orig-fn file &rest args)
  (let ((fn (if (commandp 'eaf-open) 'eaf-open orig-fn)))
    (pcase (file-name-extension file)
      ("pdf"  (apply fn file nil))
      ("epub" (apply fn file nil))
      (_      (apply orig-fn file args)))))
(advice-add #'find-file :around #'adviser-find-file)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm!